# Rails: decode text_field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have a rails app where I encode all my model data using an observer. I encode it using html codes. For example `Börje's idé` becomes `B&#246;rje&#39;s id&#233;`.

My problem now is whenever I create a form for editing.

```
<%= form_for(resource) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to force the text_field method to do some parsing (ie run it through my d() method).

I would like a solution where I don't have to modify each model and each form. Perhaps it's possible to override the `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.text_field` method?

Comment: You mean to populate the text_field with your parsed/decoded data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I found:

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb
module ActionView
    module Helpers
        class FormBuilder
            alias_method :old_text_field, :text_field

            def d(str)
                return str unless str.is_a? String

                next_str = HTMLEntities.new.decode(str)
                while (next_str != str)
                    str = next_str
                    next_str = HTMLEntities.new.decode(str)
                end
                return next_str
            end

            def text_field(method, options = {})
                @object[method] = d(@object[method])
                return old_text_field(method, options)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I guess using `instance_method` and binding it in the overwritten method would clean up the namespace a bit by making old_text_field local in scope. I am not sure how to do that but if someone wants to edit this answer and do that, feel free to do so.

Comment: This will work, but will implement this behavior for _every_ text_field.  Are you sure this is what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. As I said, I have a global observer which encodes EVERY text input (from a user) for EVERY model. So I need to decode every single field as well.